# datetime type SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Are there any ways to store the datetime type that goes outside of the type range? I mean if i try to do smth like`INSERT INTO [tbl](..., [IndependenceDate],....) VALUES(...,'1650-01-01',...)` i will get an error.(cause datetime type range is: January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999). I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: If the date does not make sense , Why not use this as varchar?

Comment: MSSQL (Microsoft Sql Server) Date Time type does indeed have a start date of 1753-01-01. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Date if you don't care about the time and have a newer version of SQL. Alternatively you can use DateTime2 (but this will use more space)...

Comment: DateTime2 does not use more space. DateTime use 8 bytes, DateTime2 can use between 6 and 8 bytes depending on it's accuracy.

Comment: Just for completion's sake, datetime2 datatype covers:
January 1, 0001 00:00:00 through December 31, 9999 23:59:59.9999999. The default value is still January 1, 1900. It's also significantly more accurate than datetime.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql